# Prove a linear transformation is the null transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been working at this problem for a while but haven't been able to get anywhere; help would be greatly appreciated!

Let $V$ be a subspace of a complex Euclidean space $E$. Let $T:V\to E$ be a linear transformation and define a scalar-valued function $Q$ as $Q(x) = (T(x),x)$, where $(x,y)$ denotes the inner product. If $Q(x) = 0$ for all $x$ prove $T(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

let B = (bi) basis of V, x = Sum(xi.bi)
Suppose now there exists x such as T(x) is different than 0.
It's evident than x is different then 0.
Now T(x) = Sum(xi.T(bi)) because T is a linear transformation
And thus (T(x), x) = (Sum(xi.T(bi)), Sum(xi.bi)) = Sum ||xi||^2(T(bi),bi)
Now, T has a non null projection on bi, else T would be the 0 application, and xi different than 0 as we supposed. which means there exists x such as Q(x) different than 0